# Why when voting to close directly on posts doesn't count for Review Badges stats?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, badges

When I am voting to close directly from a post, everything works fine, except for the part that it doesn't count for **Review Badge**. Only works if I use it through [review > close](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/8238586)

The same doesn't happen with **Suggest Edits**, whenever I see a edit suggestion that I can improve if I go to the the post directly and click on *`edit`*,after editing it adds to the counter one more (without adding one more to *`XXX posts edit`* - which to me makes sense, since that's not my entirely edition).

If I go to my [votes > closure](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3448527/dippas?tab=votes&sort=closure) I have 26 votes cast, but If I go to [review > close](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/8238586) I only have 15 votes cast.

So, with that in mind, my question is why can't close votes directly from a post count for the review stats?

Comment: I always thought it was weird that they didn't link the two.  The effect is the same.

Comment: @LanceRoberts: you cannot vote to leave open on posts. Same with the reopen queue. Or the late answers and first posts and triage and help and improvements queues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no "close badge". There are **review** badges, but when you visit a post directly you are *not reviewing existing post closures*. You cannot vote to leave a post open outside the review queue, for example.

You get badges for participating in the review process, and as part of that process you get to vote to close or to leave open posts. It is *not* the close vote itself that earns you that badge.

The only exception here is suggested edits; when you visit a post with a suggested edit pending you get to *review* that suggested edit right in the post. That's because suggested edits can block you from making another edit, so the process was streamlined there to put the specific review in front of the people that care most about that suggested edit being handled quickly.

Comment: I knew it wasn't close badges, I just couldn't remember the name at the time I was writing the question. Thanks for clearing this out ;)